# Python3 Cannot pickle self-defined objects

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

After moving a project to Python3 from Python2, I am no longer able to pickle my own objects. To restate, in python 2.7.2 I had no problems, no I get

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'mtgt.MTGTree'>: import of module 'mtgt' failed
```

I've done some searching on the web and it sounds like it has to do with the way I am importing my objects. I am using Python 3.5.2/GCC 5.4.0 20160609 on Linux. For background, I have a project with the following structure

```
* Lituus
  - \_\_init\_\_.py
  - lituus
    + \_\_init\_\_.py
    + mtg.py
    + multiverse.py
    + mtgcard.py
    + mtgl
       * \_\_init\_\_.py
       * mtgl.py
       * tagger.py
       * lexer.py
       * parser.py
       * grapher.py
       * mtgt.py
       * list_util.py
```

and I have a lituus.pth file in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages so I can run python3 from a command prompt in any directory and import my projects files

I want to pickle MTGTree objects which are defined in mtgt.py. Now if I run python3 from the directory containing mtgt and `import mtgt` I an dump the object

```
>>> import mtgt
>>> import pickle
>>> fout = open('test.pkl','wb')
>>> pickle.dump(t,fout)
>>> fout.close()
>>> exit()
```

and load the object

```
>>> import mtgt
>>> import pickle
>>> fin = open('test.pkl','rb')
>>> t = pickle.load(fin)
>>> t.root
'root'
>>> fin.close()
>>> exit()
```

and, I can even run python3 from anywhere and load the pickled tree

```
>>> import lituus.mtgl.mtgt as mtgt
>>> import pickle
>>> fin = open('test.pkl','rb')
>>> t=pickle.load(fin)
>>> fin.close()
>>> t.root
'root'
>>> exit()
```

The problem occurs when I try to dump a tree using `import.mtgl.mtgt as mtgt`

```
>>> import lituus.mtgl.mtgt as mtgt
>>> import pickle
>>> t = mtgt.MTGTree()
>>> t.root
'root'
>>> fout = open('test.pkl','wb')
>>> pickle.dump(t,fout)
```

This leads to the aforementationed 
     _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : import of module 'mtgt' failed

So, obviously I'm doing something wrong here but WTF? This works in Python 2.7 with no issues and there is no problem using pickle to load a pickled file.

I cannot find anything concrete and was hoping one of yall had some insights. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] So, in my python files, I set a list of variables for the `module.__doc__` docstring. One of these was `__name__`. After commenting this out, pickling worked fine. Stupid mistake on my part I guess but it still bothers me that Python 2.7 had no issues with it.